# PHP: Case-insensitive "array_diff"

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have following two arrays and the code to find array_diff:

```
$obs_ws = array("you", "your", "may", "me", "my", "etc");
$all_ws = array("LOVE", "World", "Your", "my", "etc", "CoDe");

$final_ws = array_diff($all_ws, $obs_ws);
```

Above code giving output array as:

```
$final_ws = array("LOVE", "World", "Your", "CoDe");
```

But I want it as:

```
$final_ws = array("LOVE", "World", "CoDe");
```

Note "Your" is not removed, it may be due to "Y" is in caps in second array. I want to exclude "Your" also, so is there any case-insensitive version of `array_diff` in PHP.

I tried **[array_udiff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php)** but I am not getting exactly how to use this in my problem

Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try to pass [`strcasecmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) as third parameter to [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) function:

```
<?php
$obs_ws = array("you", "your", "may", "me", "my", "etc");
$all_ws = array("LOVE", "World", "Your", "my", "etc", "CoDe");

$final_ws = array_udiff($all_ws, $obs_ws, 'strcasecmp');

print_r($final_ws);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => LOVE
    [1] => World
    [5] => CoDe
)
```

Comment: I believe your missing a comma. ;)

Comment: I tried it like `array_udiff($all_ws, $obs_ws, 'strcasecmp');` but its not working :(

Comment: @Prashant: Sorry, there was a small mistype in the name of the variable. Try it now. I've tested it.

Comment: But its not working, its not excluding "Your" from the resulting array ??

Comment: I've added full source and output, which works. Please test it as is.

Comment: Can't figure out what was the problem, but its working now. :) Thanks

Comment: Love thinking my issue is going to be tricky at best, only to find out that there is a built-in way to handle it, I just didn't know about it.  Thanks for the tip about `array_udiff`!

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track. This is my suggestion:

```
function array_casecmp($arr1,$arr2){
    return array_udiff($arr1,$arr2,'strcasecmp');
}


$obs_ws = array("you", "your", "may", "me", "my", "etc");
$all_ws = array("LOVE", "World", "Your", "my", "etc", "CoDe");
var_dump( array_casecmp($all_ws,$obs_ws) );
```

Comment: Why not just pass function name `'strcasecmp'` as third parameter?