# using str_replace to match whole words /case insensitive

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to replace whole words in a string using str_replace, however, even letters matched in words are being replaced. i tried preg_replace, but couldn't get it to work as i have a big list of words to replace. Any help is appreciated.

```
$array2 = array('is','of','to','page');

$text = "homepage-of-iso-image";
echo $text1 = str_replace($array2,"",$text);

the output is : home--o-image
```

Comment: This looks good to me.  What is your expected output?

Comment: the output should be homepage--iso-image. its removing "page" from "homepage", "is" from "iso"

Comment: @user2334436 if you just need to remove the `of` from your string why does `$array2` have `'is','of','to','page'`? Shouldn't it just be `'of'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the whole-words issue, there is [a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3426265/5517065) using [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), and your the solution would be to add `/\b` to the beginning and `\b/u` to the end of your array-values.  The case-insensitive could be handled with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) *(see example #1)*, but if you are working with a small array like your example, I would just recommend duplicating the array-values.

**Applied to your example:**

```
$array2 = array(
  '/\bis\b/u',
  '/\bof\b/u',
  '/\bto\b/u',
  '/\bpage\b/u',
  '/\bIS\b/u',
  '/\bOF\b/u',
  '/\bTO\b/u',
  '/\bPAGE\b/u'
);

$text = "homepage-of-iso-image";
echo $text1 = preg_replace($array2,"",$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

> ```
> array array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
> ```
>
> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

```
<?php

$remove = array('is','of','to','page');

$text   = "homepage-of-iso-image";
$parts  = explode('-', $text);

$filtered = array_diff($parts, $remove);
print implode('-', $filtered);
```

Output:

```
homepage-iso-image
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the case insensitivity part of your question.  See here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1875889/3392762